# How to integrate Facebook in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

I hava a Rails application, I need to integrate Facebook. User can login with Facebook account and get his reviews in facebook and so on, how to deal with this case in rails? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very comprehensive article here: http://www.packtpub.com/article/facebook-application-development-ruby-on-rails

And several existing plugins for this purpose like 'rfacebook', 'facebooker' or 'facebook-rails'. 'Facebooker' definitely has Facebook Connect abilities.

Answer (score 5):

Facebooker is no longer supported I recommend using Koala gem: https://github.com/arsduo/koala/wiki